# Program throws error when I increment a private static variable in C++

Tags: c++, static

I created a private static variable that keeps track of the number of elements in the linked list.

```
struct node
{
        int data;
        node *next;
};    
class linkedList
    {
            private:
                    node *head,*tail;
                    static int listSize;
            public:
                linkedList()
                {
                    head=NULL;
                    tail=NULL;
                }
                void insert(int n)
                {
                        node *temp=new node;
                        temp->data=n;
                        temp->next=NULL;
                        if(head == NULL)
                        {
                                head=temp;
                                tail=temp;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                tail->next=temp;
                                tail=temp;
                        }
                        linkedList::listSize+=1;
                }
    };
    void main()
    {
         linkedList l;
         l.insert(10);
         l.insert(20);
    }
```

The compiler throws an error when it reaches the line **linkedList::listSize+=1;**

> error: ‘linkedList’ has not been declared.

Comment: you don't need the `int` on the front of your statement

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot here.

Comment: That is not a valid C++ code. C++ can't be learned by guessing. A good [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is in order.

Comment: `static int listSize;` means you can only ever have one linked list. Reconsider making this `static`.

Comment: It should be `int linkedList::listSize+=1;`, but anyway you can't access `listSize` from n on class members as it is private...or is your actual code rather `void linkedList::insert()`...

Comment: I took out the `int`, added the missing code best I could, and it works on my machine.  I think the bug is in the code not shown.

Comment: The problem is likely header related. My money is on a circular include.

Comment: Your member function is wrongly defined too.

Comment: @user4581301 Save your money. This is pure guesswork from the OP's side.

Comment: What is `node`? [MCVE] please.

Comment: @Ron Agreed. Guesswork from my side, too.  Not much can be done with this question but close it for the time being.

Comment: node is a structure that holds a variable named data of type int and a pointer to next node. @MichaelWalz

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan you need to make all clarifications in your question. As it stands here there is too much information  missing.

Comment: [This compiles fine](https://www.ideone.com/3SIOh9), except for the missing `main`. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've added the struct and main().

Comment: There are still typos in your program, `inser(20);` instead of `insert(20);` and `:` instead of `;` in `linkedList()`.

Comment: sorry man, Those are typos which I made while editing. They are fine in the program.

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan never edit code in your question. Just copy/paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your typos corrected (`inser(20)` instead of `insert(20)` and `:` instead of `;` in `linkedList()`, your program almost compiles.

There is just one thing missing: you need to implement the `listSize` variable somewhere for example by putting `int linkedList::listSize;` before `main`:

```
...
int linkedList::listSize;   /(/ <<< add this

void main()
{
  linkedList l;
  l.insert(10);
  l.insert(20);
}
```

But why are you using a static variable for counting the elements of the list? You probably want `listSize` to be an ordinary (non static) class member, just as `head` and `tail`:

```
class linkedList
{
private:
  node * head, *tail;
  int listSize;      // no static
public:
  ...
```

and drop the `int linkedList::listSize;` suggested before.